# Cast C array into numpy array/Cython typed memoryview in Cython code

Tags: arrays, numpy, cython

I need to use a C library that gives me a function that takes as input a callback function. This callback function in turn takes an array and returns a value. So for example

```
double candidate(double[] x);
```

would be a valid callback.

I want to use Cython to implement a callback function, using Numpy to simplify the implementation.

So I am trying to implement a function

```
cdef double cythonCandidate(double[] x):
```

and now I would like to "cast" x as a numpy array immediately and then do operations using numpy.

For example, I might want to write something like:

```
cdef double euclideanNorm(double[] x):
    # cast x into a numpy array nx here - dont know how!!
    return np.sum(x * x)
```

Q1. How do I do this? How do I cast a C array into a numpy array without explicit copying, but just referencing the underlying buffer?

Q2: Is there python overhead in using numpy like I intend to?

Answer (score 5):

**For Q1:**

```
%%cython -f
import numpy as np

def test_cast():
    cdef double *x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    cdef double[:1] x_view = <double[:5]>x  # cast to memoryview, refer to the underlying buffer without copy
    xarr = np.asarray(x_view)                # numpy array refer to the underlying buffer without copy
    x_view[0] = 100
    xarr[1] = 200
    x[2] = 300
    print(xarr.flags)                       # OWNDATA flag should be False
    return x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]         # (100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 4.0, 5.0)
```

**Note**: If you don't declare the `x_view` and do this `xarr = np.asarray(<double[:5]>x)`, the cython compiler **may crash** with the error message:`AttributeError: 'CythonScope' object has no attribute 'viewscope'`.This can be fixed by `from cython cimport view`, for example:

```
%%cython -f
from cython cimport view  # comment this line to see what will happen
import numpy as np

def test_error_cast():
    cdef double *x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    xarr = np.asarray(<double[:5]>x)
    xarr[0] = 200
    return x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]
```

I don't know whether it's a feature or bug.

**For Q2:**
The numpy overhead shoud be significant when the array is small.See the benchmark below.

```
%%cython -a
from cython cimport view
import numpy as np

cdef inline double euclideanNorm(double *x, size_t x_size):
    xarr = np.asarray(<double[:x_size]>x)
    return np.sum(xarr*xarr)

cdef inline double euclideanNorm_c(double *x, size_t x_size):
    cdef double ss = 0.0
    cdef size_t i 
    for i in range(x_size):
        ss += x[i] * x[i]
    return ss

def c_norm(double[::1] x):
    return euclideanNorm_c(&x[0], x.shape[0])

def np_norm(double[::1] x):
    return euclideanNorm(&x[0], x.shape[0])
```

Small array in my PC:

```
import numpy as np
small_arr = np.random.rand(100)
print(c_norm(small_arr))
print(np_norm(small_arr))
%timeit c_norm(small_arr)   # 1000000 loops, best of 3: 864 ns per loop
%timeit np_norm(small_arr)  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 8.51 µs per loop
```

Big array in my PC:

```
big_arr = np.random.rand(1000000)
print(c_norm(big_arr))
print(np_norm(big_arr))
%timeit c_norm(big_arr)   # 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop
%timeit np_norm(big_arr)  # 100 loops, best of 3: 4.93 ms per loop
```